# Why can't I call .join() on the result of .keys()?

Tags: javascript, arrays, key

I made this JS code in an HTML file:

```
<script>
x=[];
x["abc"]={
    a:1,
    b:2
}
x["def"]={
    a:234,
    b:5655
}

keyArrayX=x.keys();
console.log(keyArrayX.join());
</script>
```

When I render the file, I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: keyArrayX.join is not a function
```

But the result of `keys()` is an array, so I don't understand what's wrong here.  My goal is to return a concatenated string of all the keys in the array, in this case it would be:

```
abc,def
```

Comment: Don't add non-integer keys to arrays. Instead, make `x` an object `x = {}` and use `Object.keys(x)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) instead of `x.keys()`;

Also `var x = {}` is correct for dictionary

```js
let x = {};

x["abc"] = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2
}
x["def"] = {
  a: 234,
  b: 5655
}

let keyArrayX = Object.keys(x);
console.log(keyArrayX.join());
```

Answer (score 2):

*"But the result of keys() is an array"*,

The return value of `keys()` is not array. According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/keys#Return_value)

> **Return value**
>   A new Array iterator object.

If you want keys then use `Object.keys()`

```js
let x=[];
x["abc"]={
    a:1,
    b:2
}
x["def"]={
    a:234,
    b:5655
}

keyArrayX=Object.keys(x);
console.log(keyArrayX.join());
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `Object.keys(x)`.

```js
x=[];
x["abc"]={
    a:1,
    b:2
}
x["def"]={
    a:234,
    b:5655
}

keyArrayX=Object.keys(x);
console.log(keyArrayX.join());
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you want to set keys in array rather than object?

```
x={}
x.abc = {};// will be the ideal way
x.def= {};
```

and then to get keys `Object.keys(x)` should be the way to go to have a map of keys

It should log `["abc", "def"]`.

`Object.keys` shall work on `x` irrespective of it's assignment as an array or an object.